# Applying a list into a dic

Tags: python, list, dictionary

my dictionary is as follows:

```
dictionary = {
        'rl':'Leader of a major right-wing party',
        'rm':'Minister or shadow minister in a major right-wing party',
        'rb':'Backbencher in a major right-wing party',
        'll':'Leader of a major left-wing party',
        'lm':'Minister or shadow minister in a major left-wing party',
        'lb':'Backbencher in a major left-wing party',
        'cr':'Crossbench member inclined to support the right wing' ,
        'cl':'Crossbench member inclined to support the left wing',
        'cn':'Genuinely non-partisan crossbench member'}

my_list = [['rl', 1], ['rm', 1], ['rb', 2], ['ll', 10], ['lm', 7], ['lb', 18], ['cr', 2], ['cl', 29]]
```

I want the output to be this:

```
1: Leader of a major right-wing party
1: Minister or shadow minister in a major right-wing party 
2: Backbencher in a major right-wing party
10: Leader of a major left-wing party
7: Minister or shadow minister in a major left-wing party 
18: Backbencher in a major left-wing party
2: Crossbench member inclined to support the right wing 
29: Crossbench member inclined to support the left wing
```

Comment: And what language might we be working in?

Comment: the code is in python

Comment: I suggest using a for loop.

Comment: I used 
for I in my_list:
 for p in dict:
    print(I,p)


this gave me the right result but it printed p for every I and vice versa, I just need 1 value to be printed from each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a for loop, what you have to do basically is to iterate over `my_list`, print `i[1]` (which is the number), put a colon after that and then print a value from the dictionary based on `i[0]`. You'll understand it better after seeing the code

```py
dictionary = {
        'rl':'Leader of a major right-wing party',
        'rm':'Minister or shadow minister in a major right-wing party',
        'rb':'Backbencher in a major right-wing party',
        'll':'Leader of a major left-wing party',
        'lm':'Minister or shadow minister in a major left-wing party',
        'lb':'Backbencher in a major left-wing party',
        'cr':'Crossbench member inclined to support the right wing' ,
        'cl':'Crossbench member inclined to support the left wing',
        'cn':'Genuinely non-partisan crossbench member'}

my_list = [['rl', 1], ['rm', 1], ['rb', 2], ['ll', 10], ['lm', 7], ['lb', 18], ['cr', 2], ['cl', 29]]

for i in my_list:
    print(f'{i[1]}: {dictionary[i[0]]}')
```

I am using a f-string here, but you can use whatever method you want to print variables and strings together, you just have to print `i[1]` and `dictionary[i[0]]`

Comment: Thankyou, I always have trouble finding the correct syntax to use to do what I want it to.

Comment: How do I keep the output as a variable.

Comment: You can store it in a list, for example, `new_list.append(f'{i[1]}: {dictionary[i[0]]}')`. Alternatively you can append it to a string, and then add a newline character. `new_string += f'{i[1]}: {dictionary[i[0]]}'` and then `new_string += '\n'` in the next line